# how to count number of pixels in image (php)

Tags: php

Please help me to count number of pixels in image, or put out the array of RGB.

So this is the script thet give me one element from array:

```
<?php
    $img = "1.png";
    $imgHand = imagecreatefrompng("$img");
    $imgSize = GetImageSize($img);
    $imgWidth = $imgSize[0];
    $imgHeight = $imgSize[1];
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"><br><br>';
    for ($l = 0; $l < $imgHeight; $l++) {
        for ($c = 0; $c < $imgWidth; $c++) {
            $pxlCor = ImageColorAt($imgHand,$c,$l);
            $pxlCorArr = ImageColorsForIndex($imgHand, $pxlCor);
        }
    }


        print_r($pxlCorArr); 
?>
```

sorry for my english i from ukraine

Comment: `$numOfPix = $imgWidth * $imgHeight;`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? total number of pixels in image as in imgwidth x imageheight or what?

Comment: I believe he wants a `$pxlCorArr` of the entire image, where the index is the pixel, and the value the colour .. else nothing of his code would make sense.

Comment: i trying to put all pixels in array and then put out RGB code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of pixels in an image is simply the height multiplied by the width.

However, I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
    $img = "1.png";
    $imgHand = imagecreatefrompng("$img");
    $imgSize = GetImageSize($img);
    $imgWidth = $imgSize[0];
    $imgHeight = $imgSize[1];
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"><br><br>';

    // Define a new array to store the info
    $pxlCorArr= array();

    for ($l = 0; $l < $imgHeight; $l++) {
        // Start a new "row" in the array for each row of the image.
        $pxlCorArr[$l] = array();

        for ($c = 0; $c < $imgWidth; $c++) {
            $pxlCor = ImageColorAt($imgHand,$c,$l);

            // Put each pixel's info in the array
            $pxlCorArr[$l][$c] = ImageColorsForIndex($imgHand, $pxlCor);
        }
    }

    print_r($pxlCorArr); 
?>
```

This will store all the pixel data for the image in the `pxlCor` and `pxlCorArr` arrays, which you can then manipulate to output what you want.

The array is a 2d array, meaning you can refrence an individual pixel with an `$pxlCorArr[y][x]` starting at `[0][0]`.

Comment: @VolodyaDaniliv I updated it to store the data in a 2d array so you can reference individual pixels with a sort of x,y coordinate in the array. Not sure if that's what you want but now that you know how it's done, I'm sure you can figure it out.